# Nginx returning 404 when accessing it through varnish server over public IP

Tags: nginx, varnish, varnish-vcl

I'm trying to serve static contents through varnish(client<-varnish<-nginx) but I'm having an issue accessing it through public IP. Varnish is working fine when accessing it locally (where varnish is running) but throws status 404 when accessing it through public IP.

My flow looks like this:

Client--> Caching_Server[NGINX(used for SSL support only) -> Varnish] --> Origin_Server[Nginx]

My varnish server config is as simple as:

```
probe healthcheck {
    .url = "http://10.10.10.3/healthcheck";
    .timeout = 2s;
    .interval = 30s;
    .window = 5;
    .threshold = 3;
}
backend default {
    .host = "10.10.10.3";
    .port = "80";
    .probe = healthcheck;
}



sub vcl_recv {

    if (req.url ~ ".ts$") {
     unset req.http.Cookie;
    }

    set req.backend_hint = default;
}
```

I also checked the Nginx logs and I see that it's throwing 404 which explains why varnish is responding with 404. But my question is why is it working when I test it locally using localhost.

Answer (score 0):

The output from `varnishlog -g request -q "ReqUrl eq '/'"` will probably give you the answer to your question.

Run the command while sending a request internally, and a request from the internet. Compare the output, and see where there's a difference.

If you need help, add the logs of both requests to your question and I'll help you examine the situation.

Comment: the issue is now solved. 
Turns out that nginx does not allow access to files unless I give it a domain name, if its running on port 80. I was trying to access nginx from varnish using a private ip on port 80.  So I changed the nginx port to 8000 and it started working fine.

Comment: @jimmy I had a hunch that this was the issue. The information I was hoping to see in the logs was the `Host` header. Glad you manage to solve the issue.